# Image-cropper angular 9 limpiar data

Tags: angular

Necesito limpiar la data del image-cropper ya que cuando el usuario intenta subir la misma imagen 2 veces, esta se bugea y no muestra nada, no muestra error ni cada solo aparece en blanco ya que el evento fileChangeEvent nunca ocurre
[dejo código en carbon](https://carbon.now.sh/XyNGZKI8G4PW3dJLdlH5)

```
  imageChangedEvent: any = "";

  croppedImage: any = "";

  fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
    this.imageChangedEvent = event;
  }
  imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    let file = this.dataURLtoFile(event.base64, "image.jpeg");
    this.imagen = file;
  }
  imageLoaded() {
    // show cropper
  }
  cropperReady() {
    // cropper ready
  }
  loadImageFailed() {
    // show message
  }
  dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
    let arr = dataurl.split(","),
      mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
      bstr = atob(arr[1]),
      n = bstr.length,
      u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
     while (n--) {
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
     }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
 }
```

Comment: Seria bueno que copiaras y pegaras el código aquí. Es mas fácil responderte.

Comment: corregido el post